# Creating a struct-of-arrays database with encapsulating interface c++

Tags: c++, database

I want to create a struct-of-arrays (SOA) database for better cache use but also have a separate interface that gives encapsulation. I am close to the design I think but would like more experienced coding eyes to have a look to critique my design. Here is what I have so far:

```cpp
struct OrbitalDataBase {
  OrbitalDataBase(std::shared_ptr<FEMDVR> a_radial_grid, std::shared_ptr<AngularGrid> a_angular_grid)
      : nbas(a_radial_grid->getNbas()), number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital(), m_orbital_coefs() {
    m_orbitals_coefs.reserve(a_radial_grid->getNbas() * a_angular_grid->getNumChannels());
}

  inline void StoreData(const uint32_t &a_ith_orbital,
                        std::shared_ptr<MOPartialWaveRepresentation> a_MO) {

    this->number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital.push_back(a_MO->getNumChannels());

    this->m_orbital_coefs.reserve(a_ith_orbital * nbas *
                                  a_MO->getNumChannels());

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nbas * a_MO->getNumChannels();
         ++i) {
      this->m_orbital_coefs.push_back(a_MO->getPartialWaveRep(i));
    }
  }

  /* private: */
  uint32_t nbas;
  std::vector<uint32_t> number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital;
  std::vector<std::complex<double>> m_orbital_coefs;
};

struct OrbitalAccessor {
  OrbitalAccessor(const OrbitalDataBase &a_orbital_data)
      : orbital_data(a_orbital_data){};

  inline std::complex<double> coef(uint32_t ith_orbital, uint32_t i) const {
    return this->orbital_data.m_orbital_coefs
        [ith_orbital * this->orbital_data.nbas *
             this->orbital_data.number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital[ith_orbital] +
         i];
  }

private:
  const OrbitalDataBase orbital_data;
};
```

How this would work is construct the database with the number of orbitals and then in a for-loop, save all the ith_orbital's coefficients in one large array. Something like this

```cpp
uint32_t number_of_orbitals = 5;
OrbitalDataBase orb_data_base(number_of_orbitals);
for (uint32_t ith_orbital = 0; ith_orbital < number_of_orbitals < ++ith_orbital)
  {
    Orbital();
    orb_data_base.StoreData(ith_orbital, femdvr_grid, orbital);
  }
```

The `Orbital()` function just creates the orbital I want to store. Then the `OrbitalAccessor` should be able to access these large arrays index with stride `ith_orbital`. I think I should pass the accessor the created database I want to access in a constructor like

```cpp
  int which_orbital = 1, int index 4; // example looks at 2nd orbital's 5th coefficient
  OrbitalAccessor orb_accessor(orb_data_base);
  orb_accessor.coef(which_orbital, index);
```

I tried to have the ObitalDataBase member data `private` but I get

> 'm_orbitals_coefs' is a private member of 'OrbitalDataBase'

so I commented the `private:` keyword so it will compile. I think they should be private for encapsulation so I'd prefer that if I am correct.

I think a better way would be to have `OrbitalAccessor` derive the `OrbitalDataBase` rather than pass it in to a constructor.

UPDATE: I changed the code a little so now the `m_orbital_coef` has a base vector capacity and resizes if it becomes larger because `a_MO->getNumChannels()` can be larger than `a_angular_grid->getNumChannels()`.

Comment: if it doesn't compile you have to fix it prior to posting here

Comment: With SOA, do you mean "Service-oriented architecture"? Please expand acronyms you use at least once so people know what exactly you are talking about.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast Ah shoot sorry, thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot missing from this question, but there is enough code to be able to tell that a lot that could be improved.  Here are some ideas for improving your code.

### Use all of the required `#include`s

All of the `#includes` for this code are missing in the description.  I believe the required list is this:

```
#include <complex>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
```

### Provide complete code to reviewers

This is not so much a change to the code as a change in how you present it to other people.  Without the full context of the code and an example of how to use it, it takes more effort for other people to understand your code.  This affects not only code reviews, but also maintenance of the code in the future, by you or by others.  One good way to address that is by the use of comments.  Another good technique is to include test code showing how your code is intended to be used.  There is a bit of that in your question, so we'll start from there.

### Start with the desired interface

It's usually very useful to start by imagining how we'd like to use the code before implementing the interface.  It appears that there exists some external source of orbital data (I'm guessing [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set)) which this code is supposed to read and parse (not shown) and then provide storage and access methods.  First, rather than two separate classes, `OrbitalDataBase` and `OrbitalAccessor`, it seems clear to me that there should rather be a single `OrbitalDataBase` and that the accessor should be a member function.  That leads to the first simplification:

```
std::complex<double> coef(uint32_t ith_orbital, uint32_t i) const {
    return m_orbital_coefs[ith_orbital * nbas * number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital[ith_orbital] + i];
}
```

### Don't write this->

Within member functions `this->` is redundant. It adds visual clutter and does not usually aid in understanding.

### Use more whitespace for clarity

It's very difficult to parse the `OrbitalDataBase` constructor because it's all run together with very little whitespace.  I'd modify it to look more like this:

```
struct OrbitalDataBase {
  OrbitalDataBase(std::shared_ptr<FEMDVR> a_radial_grid, std::shared_ptr<AngularGrid> a_angular_grid)
      : nbas(a_radial_grid->getNbas())
      , number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital()
      , m_orbital_coefs() 
{
    m_orbital_coefs.reserve(a_radial_grid->getNbas() * a_angular_grid->getNumChannels());
}
```

### Don't explicitly invoke implied constructors

The constructor, reformatted as above, reveals that the default and implied constructors for `number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital` and `m_orbital_coefs` are explicitly called.  This is both unnecessary and unhelpful.  Simply omit those two lines.

### Prefer `const` references to smart pointers

If you are passing in data, such as the `FEMDVR` and `AngularGrid` in this code, that are used but not altered, this implies `const`.  Further, if we are not sharing ownership, which appears to be the case here, these should be references rather than `std::shared_ptr`.

```
OrbitalDataBase(const FEMDVR& a_radial_grid, const AngularGrid& a_angular_grid)
    : nbas(a_radial_grid.getNbas())
{
    m_orbital_coefs.reserve(nbas * a_angular_grid.getNumChannels());
}
```

### Understand modern use of `inline`

Based on how you're using it, it appears that you are abusing the `inline` keyword to get an effect that the compiler is already going to provide without it.  That is the [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) specifier for functions used to be a request to the compiler to optimize by putting the code inline rather than creating an explicit function call.  However, this was only ever a suggestion, and the changing semantics of `inline` for C++17 and beyond are likely to lead to trouble unless very carefully used.  The reason is that, starting with C++17, it tells the compiler that multiple defifinitions are allowed, but if they differ in any way, invoking the function is undefined behavior.  For these reasons, you're better off omitting `inline` in most cases.

### Rethink your data structures

Right now getting a value back uses this rather complex form:

```
std::complex<double> coef(uint32_t ith_orbital, uint32_t i) const {
    return m_orbital_coefs[ith_orbital * nbas * number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital[ith_orbital] + i];
}
```

This is very cache unfriendly because it has to look up one value from `number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital` and then use that to index into another vector.  It may make things more clear and give better performance if instead you defined a `struct` or `class` that encapsulated both.  The obvious would be this:

```
struct Orbital {
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> m_orbital_coefs;
};
```

Then `OrbitalDataBase` could use `std::vector<Orbital>` as its only data member, since the number of coefficients is `m_orbital_coefs.size()` and `nbas` is now `m_orbital_coefs.size()`.

Even simpler might be this:

```
using Orbital = std::vector<std::complex<double>>;
```

Comment: I am confused with your suggestion for restructuring the data, could you explain a little more?  The cache performance is from saving all the orbitals coefficients in one vector strided by nbas * number_of_lm_pairs_per_orbital[ith_orbital], so all of the elements for each orbital are contiguous in memory.